# How to show both the layout and the message?

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a message activity and it works but my problem is the xml layout that I created is not showing, only the message or vice versa (the layout is showing without the message).How do I solve this?

here is the code of the class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra (MESSAGE_KEY);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText (message);
        setContentView(textView);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fire_alert);
    }
```

and here is the xml file that i want to show

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.user.tictactoeniandy.FireAlertActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="View Sender Location"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
        android:id="@+id/loc_button1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation:"vertical" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.user.tictactoeniandy.FireAlertActivity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loc_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="View Sender Location"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="View Sender Location"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
            android:id="@+id/loc_button1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and in your activity code,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fire_alert);        
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra (MESSAGE_KEY);
        TextView textView = (TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.loc_textview);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText (message);


    }
```

you can have only one set content view. try to update your layout and code with mine and check it will show both.

Comment: It works! so if I add another ImageView can i do the same method ?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, yes you can do that with same way, but i would prefer that you will read basic about android development and move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have 1 content view.  The second one you set overwrites the other.  The correct way to do this is to have a TextView inside your layout, and to set the text on that view to the message

Comment: Best answer. Simple and direct to the point. No code, just directions.

Comment: I'm just new at programming so this is really useful :)

Answer (score 0):

The `setContentView()` method, as the name suggests, sets the content of your activity. To solve this, place your `TextView` directly on your layout file, for example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
...>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="
        ...
         .../>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On your Java code, make a `TextView` using the id you just created on your layout, then set the message text on it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fire_alert);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.text_view_message);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra (MESSAGE_KEY);
    textView.setText (message);
}
```